# How to get variable in Flexible File Writer in JMeter

Tags: automated-testing, jmeter, api-testing, jmeter-plugins

I was testing service with JMeter. I need to write the `phone` number into a CSV file and the phone number is a variable as you can see in the `Debug Sampler`. I was using `Flexible File Writer` for writing the file. [Here](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FlexibleFileWriter/?utm_source=jmeter&utm_medium=helplink&utm_campaign=FlexibleFileWriter) is the documentation of `Flexible File Writer` in the last section they described how to use a variable but I'm not getting it. Any example would be great help!

[image]

Here is my `Flexible File Writer` config

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add the next line to *user.properties* file:

   ```
    sample_variables=phone
   ```
2. Restart JMeter to pick up the change
3. Instead of `${phone}` in the Flexible File Writer use `variable#0`
4. If you need to write more than one variable:

   ```
   sample_variables=phone,device_id
   ```

   and then in the Flexible File Writer:

   - `variable#0` - instead of `${phone}`
   - `variable#1` - instead of `${device_id}`

More information:

- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Sample Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables)
- [Using the JMeter Flexible File Writer Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-the-jmeter-flexible-file-writer-plugin)

Comment: still not getting
```
# Sample user.properties file
sample_variables=phone,verify_token
```
Restarted several times.
`variable#0,variable#1\n`

Answer (score 0):

1. Declare the `sample_variables=Name,email` in `user.properties` file.
2. Restart the JMeter.
3. In script example :
   `WDS.vars.put("Name", Namevalue); WDS.vars.put("email", emailvalue);`
4. Record each sampe as : set the |variable#0| Instead of `${Name}` and |variable#1| Instead of `${email}` in the Flexible File Writer.